# Why the arrows of two edges are not appearing in tkz-graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

I am creating a figure using tkz-graph. But there are two arrows of the edges are missing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\renewcommand*{\EdgeLineWidth}{0.15pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style = {->}}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {minimum size = 24 pt}}
\Vertex[Math, L=f(s)]{A}
\Vertex[Math, L=s_1, x=-8,y=-2]{B}
\Vertex[Math, L=-s_1,x=-6,y=-2]{C}
\Vertex[Math, L=\dots, x=-4,y=-2]{D}
\Vertex[Math, L=s_j, x=-2,y=-2]{E}
\Vertex[Math, L=-s_j,x=0,y=-2]{F}
\Vertex[Math, L=\dots, x=2,y=-2]{G}
\Vertex[Math, L=s_{n-1}, x=4,y=-2]{H}
\Vertex[Math, L=-s_{n-1}, x=6,y=-2]{I}
\Vertex[Math, L=s_n, x=8,y=-2]{J}
\Edges(A, B)
\Edges (A, C)
\Edges( A, D)
\Edge[style={->}](A)(E)
\Edges( A, F)
\Edges( A, G)
\Edges( A, H)
\Edges( A, I)
\Edges( A, J)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The plot produced looks like follows:[image]
The two edges around the middle lose the arrow. I tried differently but no success.

Comment: Did you try `\Edges (A, E)` like others?

Comment: @Sigur: Yes. Still not working.

Comment: @Sigur: Actually, the edges (A, E) and (A, G) are both missing arrows and I used different ways for these two.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. It works here. Did you zoom the image to see it?

Comment: Also, please add the first line of code, that is, the document class you are using. I tested with `article` and it works. I'm using updated TeXlive 2018.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to zoom in and actually the arrow appears as I zoomed to around 500% size. Is there a way to make it look normal in the normal size.

Comment: Well, I have no idea, since it is completely right here. Maybe it is problem with pdf reader, or version of TikZ you have, or could be a lot of possibilities.

Comment: I think it is due to `\renewcommand*{\EdgeLineWidth}{0.15pt}`; try to use a higher value.

Comment: @manooooh: Thanks. 0.3 or higher works.

Comment: @marmot: This is solved by manooooh's comment on \Edgelinewidth.

Comment: @marmot I am not sure if that is the only thing to change; it is better that you answer in a proper way. You have all the permissions granted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome!! [As said in comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476224/why-the-arrows-of-two-edges-are-not-appearing-in-tkz-graph?noredirect=1#comment1202113_476224), you have to change the value of `\renewcommand*{\EdgeLineWidth}{0.15pt}` to a higher one. OP said that the best value is `0.3pt` (or higher).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\renewcommand*{\EdgeLineWidth}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style = {->}}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {minimum size = 24 pt}}
\Vertex[Math, L=f(s)]{A}
\Vertex[Math, L=s_1, x=-8,y=-2]{B}
\Vertex[Math, L=-s_1,x=-6,y=-2]{C}
\Vertex[Math, L=\dots, x=-4,y=-2]{D}
\Vertex[Math, L=s_j, x=-2,y=-2]{E}
\Vertex[Math, L=-s_j,x=0,y=-2]{F}
\Vertex[Math, L=\dots, x=2,y=-2]{G}
\Vertex[Math, L=s_{n-1}, x=4,y=-2]{H}
\Vertex[Math, L=-s_{n-1}, x=6,y=-2]{I}
\Vertex[Math, L=s_n, x=8,y=-2]{J}
\Edges(A, B)
\Edges (A, C)
\Edges( A, D)
\Edge[style={->}](A)(E)
\Edges( A, F)
\Edges( A, G)
\Edges( A, H)
\Edges( A, I)
\Edges( A, J)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE's output]